# Seeding huge amount of data (EF Core)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Here is the script which I use manually after the database creating to generate useless data for testing:

```
DECLARE @index BIGINT

SET @index = 0
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Persons ON

WHILE @index < 50000
BEGIN   
    INSERT INTO Persons
        (Id, [Name], Code)
    VALUES
        (NEWID(), CONCAT('Person', @index), @index)

    SET @index = @index + 1
END
```

How can I run it using EF core in the moment of the database initialization or somehow using data seeding methods? All the answers around are about small amounts of data, but in my case, I work with ~ 50000 records.

Comment: FYI, there are *far* better (faster) ways of creating 50,000 rows than a `WHILE`.

Comment: There should not be any difference between a small file and huge file except the time it takes to run.  For huge data do not use Express which has limits to size of the database.  also make sure the disk where the database is stored is fast.  Also make sure database is local and not remote.  The time to send the data over a network connection will slow down the saving.

Comment: @jdweng "_Also make sure database is local and not remote_" that code would not be severely penalized on networking, it is only one SQL sent to the server and is the server the one doing the loop

Comment: If you are running SQL Server Management Studio and script is running on local SSMS and database is on another SQL Server on remote machine wouldn't data get transferred over the network?  On a fast network the transfer time would be small be still add time.   If you were on a network where a virus checker was validating the data that also would add time.

Comment: Let your test suite run this code, not EF.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using EF Core 2.1 and higher, then making use of [HasData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding) method is an ideal way to add seed data.

We can call it using ModelBuilder object in 'OnModelCreating' method to add the data as part of code first migrations.The data then gets seeded the very first time when a database is scaffold or initialized and migrations are applied.

You can also combine it with [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) to generate fake data for entities.

Inline is a scenario for creating 50000 objects as stated in question. The program executed successfully without any issues. In fact ef core is intelligent enough to split the data into batch queries of 700-800 objects per batch and push it to database.

Entity:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

OnModelCreating

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    int id = 1;
    var fakePersons = new Faker<Person>().StrictMode(true)
        .RuleFor(o => o.Id, f => id++)
        .RuleFor(u => u.FirstName, (f, u) => f.Name.FirstName())
        .RuleFor(u => u.LastName, (f, u) => f.Name.LastName());

    var persons = fakePersons.Generate(50000);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasData(persons);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use EF's seeding for this amount of data. Also, it's only for testing. It shouldn't be part of the main application's code base.

Comment: My answer primarily focuses on OP question, i.e whether there is a provision to seed huge amount of data in ef core.